# How to calculate the damping coefficient using the tagent delta value?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring, oscillators, dissipation, coupled-oscillators

**The Problem**

I have a mechanical system with multiple degrees of freedom like this one:
[image]

And I am given the following information:

1. The mass $m$ in (kg)
2. The spring constants $k$ in (N/m)
3. The damping coefficients $b$ in (Ns/m)

This is fairly straightforward to solve, as the matrix differential equation would be as follows:

$$M\ddot{X} + B\dot{X} + KX = F(t)$$

In a slightly more complex version of the above, instead of point 3, the only information available regarding the system's damping is the following:

3. The external damping is provided as a series of identical coefficients $c$ in (Ns/m).
4. The internal damping as a series of identical values $\tan \delta$ (e.g. $\tan \delta=0.04$).

**My Questions**

1. What is the difference between what is considered internal and external damping on a system with multiple degrees of freedom such as the one in the figure above?
2. And most importantly: What is the physical meaning value of $\tan\delta$ (sometimes refered to as loss factor I think), and how is it related to the internal damping coefficient $b$?